# BIGQUERY csv file load with an additional column with a default value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

From the example given by Google, I have managed to load CSV files into BigQuery(BQ) table following the guide(link and code below)
Now I want to add several files into BQ, and want to add a new column `filename` which contains the filename.

Is there a way to add column with default data?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

```
// Import the Google Cloud client libraries
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Instantiate clients
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const storage = new Storage();

/**
 * This sample loads the CSV file at
 * https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv
 *
 * TODO(developer): Replace the following lines with the path to your file.
 */
const bucketName = 'cloud-samples-data';
const filename = 'bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv';

async function loadCSVFromGCS() {
  // Imports a GCS file into a table with manually defined schema.

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
   */
  // const datasetId = 'my_dataset';
  // const tableId = 'my_table';

  // Configure the load job. For full list of options, see:
  // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad
  const metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'CSV',
    skipLeadingRows: 1,
    schema: {
      fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'post_abbr', type: 'STRING'},
//      {name: 'filemame', type: 'STRING', value=filename} // I WANT TO ADD COLUMN WITH FILE NAME HERE
      ],
    },
    location: 'US',
  };

  // Load data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
  const [job] = await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata);

  // load() waits for the job to finish
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);

  // Check the job's status for errors
  const errors = job.status.errors;
  if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
    throw errors;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have a few choices.

1. Add a column to the CSV before uploading, e.g. [with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506810/add-column-to-end-of-csv-file-using-awk-in-bash-script) or preprocessing in JS.
2. Add the individual CSV files to separate tables. You can easily [query across many tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) as one in BigQuery. This way you can easily see what data comes from which file, and you can access [table meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227123/select-table-name-as-a-column-in-bigquery) data for the file-name
3. Post process the data, by adding the column after the data is loaded with normal sql/[api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-add-column-query-append) calls.
4. See also this possible duplicate [How to add new column with metadata value to csv when loading it to bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957488/how-to-add-new-column-with-metadata-value-to-csv-when-loading-it-to-bigquery)

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna go with option 2.

Answer (score 2):

According to BigQuery’s documentation [1], there is no option to set a default value for columns. The closest option without any post-processing, would be to use a NULL value for nullable columns.

However, a possible postprocessing workaround for this would be to create a View of the raw table and add a script that maps the NULL value to any default value. Here’s some information about scripting in BigQuery [2].

In case it is possible to add a pre-processing code, adding the value to the source file would be easy to achieve using any scripting language.

I think that static and function-based values will be a good feature for BigQuery’s future scope.

[1] -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs

[2] -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. you could rebuild your CSV with the filename as a column data
2. you can load data into a temporary table, then moving to final table with a second step specifying the missing file name column
3. convert the example to be an external table where `_FILE_NAME` is a pseduocolumn, and later you can query and move to a final table. See more about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column).